# How to get the foreign key column that auto created by ef core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Hello I want to implement a one to many relationship with only one entity with itself, but I want to access the foreign key that auto generated by Ef, unfortunately, I tested many ways such as using fluent api and give a parentId as foreign key e.g, but all of them got errors, these are my classes:

```
public class EntityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

```
 public class Category : EntityBase
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool ShowInMenu { get; set; }
public List<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
}
```

when I run the command Add-Migration, the migration produces this class for me :

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "CategoryId",
                table: "ProductCategories",
                type: "int",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_ProductCategories_CategoryId",
                table: "ProductCategories",
                column: "CategoryId");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ProductCategories_ProductCategories_CategoryId",
                table: "ProductCategories",
                column: "CategoryId",
                principalTable: "ProductCategories",
                principalColumn: "Id");
```

And I want to access the data of the column CategoryId auto generated by ef from my code, but I don't know how can I do this? could anyone please help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't want a "shadow property" then define the column exactly the same as any other relationship (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#accessing-shadow-properties) related with shadow properties

I tried as below:

In dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().Property<int?>("CategoryId").IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(x=>x.ChildCategories).WithOne().HasForeignKey("CategoryId").IsRequired(false).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
```

Access target Fk:

```
var targetfk = _context.Entry<Category>(targetitem).Property("CategoryId").CurrentValue;
```

Worked as expected:

[image]

[image]